# Turing machine notation, need translation

Tags: computer-science, automata, turing-machines

Im learning about Turing machines and have seen examples like this:
[image: Example 1]

For example if we stand in state "A" and read "0" we replace it with "P" and move right.

However I came across this in old exams:
[image: Example 2]

How am I to read this TM? for example in the middle we have $\#R_\#L$.

I am asked to describe the language over the alphabet $\{a,b\}$ that the TM represents. But I am unaware on how to read the machine at all.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately neither graphical nor textual notation for Turing machines is anywhere near standardized, and each author/lecturer just makes something up that they hope they can pass off as reasonably intuitive. The second of your examples here is definitely on the more cryptic side; I have no idea what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: Well that is just depressing.

Answer (score 2):

The first Turing Machine is a Turing Machine represented in the form of states.
The second one is a "complex" Turing Machine represented in the form of basic Turing machines. Complex in the sense that it is made up of smaller, more basic Turing Machines combined in some form.

**R<sub>a</sub>** is a Turing Machine whose head shifts right in the input tape until it reads *a*. **"#"** is a Turing Machine which replaces the input symbol pointed by the head in the input tape to **"#"**.

Finally a Turing machine **R<sub>a</sub>L** is equivalent to: 
**R<sub>a</sub>**  **→** **L**
This means the equivalent Turing Machine as a whole will move to the right until it finds an *a* in the input tape; the arrow without any symbols represents that the Turing Machine will move to the left(since 'L' Turing Machine is present on the end of the arrow) on the encounter of any symbol in the alphabet.

I recommend you read **'Elements of The Theory of Computation'** written by *Harry R. Lewis* if you still don't understand.